# Initializing (list) properties in constructor using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, properties, initialization-list

I am trying to initialize all properties in class (lists) with using reflection:

```
public class EntitiesContainer
{
    public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }

    public EntitiesContainer()
    {
        var propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in propertyInfo)
        {
            property.SetValue(property, Activator.CreateInstance(property.GetType()), null);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting exception:

> No constructor has been defined for this object without parameters.

I would appreciate tips.

Comment: you need to pass some parameters with `CreateInstance`. one of those types expects some more information.

Comment: and you can't create an instance of an interface!

Comment: this seems like a bad idea working against the compiler...

Comment: I am new in reflection

Comment: how to istantiate list of type var typeOf = property.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0], to get new List<typeOf>?

Comment: @H.Wojtowicz I discussed that in my answer: `typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(...)`

Answer (score 4):

You *can* do this provided that you define the properties as concrete types. This actually works:

```
public class EntitiesContainer
{
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    public List<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }

    public EntitiesContainer()
    {
        var propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in propertyInfo)
        {
            property.SetValue(this, Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType));
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot create an instance of an `IEnumerable<T>` because it's an interface.

But why would you want to to this? You'd better initialize the properties using the auto-property initializer that was introduced in C#6:

```
public class EntitiesContainer
{
    public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>;
    public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; } = new List<Address>;
    public IEnumerable<Contract> Contracts { get; set; } = new List<Address>;
}
```

Comment: I have many more properties and it can chcange in time, that's why

Comment: @H.Wojtowicz when you add something new, just follow the pattern that exists.

Answer (score 3):

In general here, the type of object you want to create is `property.PropertyType`; and the object upon which you want to set the value is `this`, so:

```
property.SetValue(this, Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType), null);
```

But! your properties are `IEnumerable<T>`, not `List<T>` - can't create an interface, only a concrete type. So you'd have to do a lot of work with deconstructing the generic `IEnumerable<Foo>` to `Foo` (`var args = type.GetGenericTypeArguments()`) and constructing a `List<Foo>` (`typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(args)`). Or just change the property types to `List<T>`!

Frankly, it would be easier to just do:

```
public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>();
public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
public IEnumerable<Contract> Contracts { get; set; } = new List<Contract>();
```

or:

```
public List<Address> Addresses { get; } = new List<Address>();
public List<Person> People { get; } = new List<Person>();
public List<Contract> Contracts { get; } = new List<Contract>();
```

Comment: @H.Wojtowicz you do realize that the reflection approach will be considerably less efficient *and* hard to maintain, right? (note: reflection *can* be made extremely efficient, but it takes a lot more work)

Answer (score 1):

To sum up what I wanted to acheive was method called in constructor like below:

```
    private void InitializeAllCollections()
    {
        var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var genericType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
            var creatingCollectionType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(genericType);
            property.SetValue(this, Activator.CreateInstance(creatingCollectionType));
        }
    }
```

Thanks guys for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need:  when creating business objects for unit tests, I want to default all uninitialized Lists to new Lists, so that if a test needs to add something to a list, I don't have to worry about initializing it there.  And like the OP, I have too many business objects to change them all to default.  My solution is a mix of the others; the exceptions being I only want List properties, and only if they are not yet initialized:

```
    public static T DefaultLists<T>(this T obj)
    {
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(q => q.PropertyType.Name == "List`1" && q.GetValue(obj) == null);
        foreach(var property in properties)
            property.SetValue(obj, Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType));

        return obj;
    }
```

Now my sample object creator can return new businessObject.DefaultLists();